# Call native Delphi code from C#

Tags: c#, delphi, com, native-code, managed-code

Are there any best practices to call native C++ or Delphi Dlls from C# (ASP.NET)? Is invoking or a COM interop the best way to access those Dlls?

Comment: I suggest going for a wrapper in managed C++.
what exactly do you wanna do?

Comment: This explains your options: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnts/archive/2010/05/03/call-native-c-dll-from-c-code.aspx

Comment: 2 minutes.. Just _too_ long.

Comment: You have 2 options: use COM interop or Platform Invoke. Both choices are valid. If you have a COM object - use COM interop, otherwise use P/Invoke.

Comment: I don't have any COM objects so far ... just some simple license calculation functions, written in Delphi.

Comment: If you only have a handful of functions, I'd say p/invoke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DllImport to achieve your objective, as per the following:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(uint dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);
```

You can use this with any Win32 compatible DLL, including Delphi ones.

Comment: Does this also works on 64bit machines calling 32bit DLLs? Or do I have to provide the 64bit DLLs of the native code for those cases?

Comment: @Konrad If you build your C# code as x86 then you provide 32-bit DLL. If you build as "AnyCPU" you need to provide 32-bit DLL on x86 OS, and 64-bit DLL on x64 OS.